# Improving code to draw several cycles trigonometric

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I improve this code to generate three cycles varying the height of the trigonometric tangent? Note that I managed to correctly draw the red line, but could not improve the green line.
What I want is a reduction in their angle and straight.
The green line does not have the correct height.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=2]
\foreach \radius in {1,2,3}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YValue}{tan(60/\radius)*\radius}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\sinus}{sin(60/\radius)*\radius}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cosinus}{cos(60/\radius)*\radius}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=3*\radius cm]
        \draw circle (1);
        %axis
        \draw[->] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) coordinate (x);
        \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);
        %angles
        \fill[fill=green!25] (0,0) -- (.2,0) arc (0:60/\radius:.2) -- cycle;
        %sinus
        \coordinate (P) at (60/\radius:1);
        \draw[<-,red,line width=1pt] (P) -- (P |- x);
        \fill[blue] (P) circle (1pt);
        \draw (0,0) -- (P);
        %cosinus
        \draw[->,orange] (0,0) -- (P |- 0,0);
        %tangent
        \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (1,\YValue);
        \draw[->,green,line width=1pt] (1,0) -- (1,\YValue);
    \end{scope}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the green line is the tangent of the green angle. Then you should rewrite the formulae in the `\foreach` loop like this:

```
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\YValue}{tan(60/\radius)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\sinus}{sin(60/\radius)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cosinus}{cos(60/\radius)}
```

[image]